# Files in Folder named "templates" don't apply colors and suggest in VisualStudioCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

If I name the folder "templates" or "template", the files in the folder don't apply colors or suggest in VisualStudio Code.
1st image shows when I named the folder "templates", and 2nd one shows when I named the folder "foo" (flutter).
I'm not sure but this happens maybe because of a extension that I added?
Please tell me how can I avoid this.

[image: named templates]
[image]

This is my setting of `files.associations`:
[image: setting]

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
Yes, It seems that I have some associations, and one of them was like this:
`Files: Associations
Configure file associations to languages (e.g. "*.extension": "html"). These have precedence over the default associations of the languages installed.`
And the file was interpreted as Django txt.
So should I remove this association?
I really don't know how the associations work, so I'm sorry if I'm saying something weired.

Comment: The image shows that you do _not_ have any file associations set. Did you already remove the association you were referring to?

Comment: I don't think I remove anything, but changing the type of file being interpreted fixed it. Thank you for your support! I really appreciate you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated by the asker in the comments, the issue is due to file associations. Check your settings.json file to see if you have anything set in the `"files.associations"` setting that could be causing this. Otherwise, try disabling extensions that aren't needed to see if they are related to the issue. You can also change what file association is being used by clicking the lanugage indicator on the bottom right of the screen that has a "Select Language Mode" hover message. The same action can be done by using the command palette and using the "`Change Language Mode`" command.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I got it solved by disabling extension "Django" by publisher "Baptiste Darthenay".